# Why can I not use a filter for my Map?

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections, types, filter

I'm getting a strange type mismatch error in Scala when I try to do the following:

```
val m = Map[String, Int]("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3)
val n = Map[String, Int]("c" -> 3, "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5)
n.filter((k: String, v: Int) => !m.contains(k))
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (String, Int) => Boolean
 required: (String, Int) => Boolean
              n.filter((k: String, v: Int) => !m.contains(k))
```

Am I doing something wrong?  The type mismatch doesn't make sense here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The actual required type is `((String,Int))`, i.e. a single argument that's a `Pair[String,Int]`, but your syntax is passing two separate arguments. You can pass in a partial function instead, which uses the `case` keyword to match the pair:

```
n.filter { case(k, v) => !m.contains(k) }
```

Here's a [Relevant article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/scala-pattern-matching-pair) about it.

Luigi deserves props for pointing out that `filterKeys` is a more appropriate method to use here.

Comment: Since value is not used, one might consider: `n.filter{case(k, _) => !m.contains(k) }`

Answer (score 9):

The unhelpful error message is a known bug in Scala 2.9.

What it should say is

```
 found   : (String, Int) => Boolean
 required: ((String, Int)) => Boolean
```

I.e. you've supplied a `Function2[String, Int, Boolean]` when `filter` requires a `Function1[(String, Int), Boolean]`.

You can use pattern matching to match on tuples as Nick shows, directly provide a tuple function as Tomasz shows, or you can turn your `Function2` into `Function1` taking a tuple using the `tupled` method:

```
n.filter(((k: String, v: Int) => !m.contains(k)).tupled)
// or
n.filter(Function.tupled((k, v) => !m.contains(k)))
```

But you're best-off using the built-in `filterKeys` method:

```
n.filterKeys(!m.contains(_))
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out it being a 2.9 bug (just noticed I tried it out in 2.8 so I got the correct error message), and for mentioning `filterKeys`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
n.filter(entry => !m.contains(entry._1))
```

Where `entry` is a tuple containing `(key, value)` so `entry._1` is a key.